# XMLDBException: Failed to invoke method retrieve in class

Tags: java, xml, exists

I'm using eXist as a DBMS for both XML and binary data.
I'm interacting with it through a Java program using XMLDB API.
To store my data i use the *xmldb:store* function in an XQuery in this way:

```
xmldb:store('Collection Name', 'Id','Document Contents') //for XML documents

xmldb:store('Collection Name', 'Id','Base64 Encoded Contents', 'application/octet-stream') //for binary data
```

I'm trying to write a program that reads the files in a folder and saves them in the database calling the right store function for each file.
The binary data is composed by images, pdf files, some swf animations and so on..

When i launch the program for most resources the upload completes without errors, but for some of them i get this exception:

*XMLDBException: Failed to invoke method retrieve in class org.exist.xmlrpc.RpcConnection: result set unknown or timed out*

Everytime i launch the program this error shows on different files. On a directory containing about 250 files i get between 7 to 12 errors.
I thought it could be a timeout that expires, but the eXist server is on a virtual machine so the communication is very fast, plus the files contained in the directory are of different types and i get the error even on small xml files while, for example, it stores much larger swf animations.

All the request to the server are sequential and there is no other user except me that uses it.

I really hope someone can give me some advice to understand what the cause could be.
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found another way to do the same thing. I solved the problem using XML:DB API to store directly the files i needed instead of executing an XQuery.

So i used Collection.createResource and Collection.storeResource and all worked :)